# Results on magnitude of the column space of a complex matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

Let $y = Ax$ where $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times m},$ $x \in \mathbb{C}^m,$ $n>m,$ and $A$ has full column rank. Then $y$ is in a subspace of $\mathbb{C^n}$, the $m$-dimensional $C(A).$

Define $|y| = \begin{pmatrix} |y_1| \\ \vdots \\ |y_n| \end{pmatrix},$ i.e., the vector of the magnitudes of the elements of $y.$

Does anyone know any general results for $|y|$ (equiv., $|Ax|$)?

For example, if $n > 2m$, then I believe that $|y|$ is in a $2m$-dimensional (or less) subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n.$ How would one prove this?

Comment: For a general $A$, it might not be true that $C(A)$ is $m$-dimensional. For example, if $A=0$, then $C(A)$ is $0$-dimensional.

Comment: Indeed. I should have stated that $A$ has full rank.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you mean |y| = $\begin{pmatrix} |y1| \\ |y2| \end{pmatrix}$ I think it's going to depend on the nature of A.  For example if A = $\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
0 & 0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}$

|Ax| (and for that matter Ax) will span only a 1 dimensional space.

Comment: Indeed. I updated the question to clarify that $A$ has full rank.